# How can I clustering multiple images in a folder?

Tags: image, grouping, cluster-analysis

Due the Hard Failure I lost the separated photos. The I recovered them using image recovery. But now all the images are in one folder. Those images may be over 500 in the same one folder.

- The images have customized names also.
- The images are not in the same size also.
- The images are not in same dimension also.

I am unable to cluster them and separate them in to a new folder as manually and time consuming. So, is there any online solution or software to automatically cluster them and move them into a folder?

For example :

**Image set 1** : [image: A set of photos has the same background]

**Image set 2** : [image: A set of image has the same background]

**Image set 3** : [image: A set if images has the same background]

In the above set of pictures, every image has the same background. So those images should be clustered as one and put them in a folder.

As like this, is there any solution or API level solution to simplify the manual works?

Comment: This asks for software recommendations.

Comment: Not only software recommendation and also online API solutions too.

Comment: Neither of which is on-topic for stackoverflow...

Answer (score 0):

If they are JPEG images, you can try running `jhead` on them and it should be able to find the dates in the files. See [jhead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead//).

It can then rename the files based on the date for you, then you could separate them by their names/dates.

It may also tell you the GPS latitude/longitude, so you could move them to folders based on their proximity to each other.

Try the `-v` option to see the full information in a file:

```
jhead -v recovered123.jpg
```

Comment: Will it automatically move the image set in to a folder? And finding by date time is also bit tricky. But I will better if that finds by the image content , not the meta data.

Comment: It does what I suggested - so you would either need to group by date or GPS location... as each group of photos appears to represent a holiday or a party, that should be a pretty reasonable start. Anything else is likely to need significant software development, probably with AI, and testing that would take many, many times longer than manually sorting 500 photos by hand.

Comment: Yeah!, That's good but some photos does not have GPS location, while they were taken that option disabled. So, any suggestion, please

Comment: And as I said before, GPS location may be the meta data. So, is there any solution or API for image vision?

Answer (score 0):

Get the *time* information from the EXIF metadata.

Use this to automatically name and sort the images. Since you likely did not operate two cameras at two different events at the same time, this will work extremely well. Unlesw you managed to destroy this metadata.

Comment: Other than time information, any solution with the content of the image?

Comment: Well, you certainly can try BOVW and DCNN. But I doubt you will "just" get this to work if you don't spend a year of work on it (or have done this before).

Comment: Oh! sad, is there any related tutorials or online solutions?

Comment: Yes, plenty. You can find them with Google.